# How to print Fastreport directly without showing any Dialog in my Application?

Tags: fastreport

```
fsReport.RegisterData(ds);
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++) {
  if (fsReport.GetDataSource(ds.Tables[i].TableName) != null) {
    fsReport.GetDataSource(ds.Tables[i].TableName).Enabled = True;
  }
}
fsReport.PrintSettings.Printer = PrinterNameForPrintAtumatice;
fsReport.PrintSettings.ShowDialog = false;

if (fsReport.Prepare()) {
  fsReport.Print();
}
```

this code show Access Data Dialog, how To solve this? Do not Show Any Dialog? Access Data Dialog In my System show.
Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
FastReport.Utils.Config.ReportSettings.ShowProgress = false;
```